# Book about a class pet that turns into a dinosaur

Tags: story-identification, novel, dinosaurs

In this book, the class pet gets turned into a T. Rex or Allosaurus and causes havoc in the neighborhood. At the end, it eats a teacher and its revealed that aliens turned the lizard into a dinosaur. Does anyone know what book this is?

Comment: What species of animal was the class pet?

Answer (score 4):

[*Hamstersaurus Rex*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28512635-hamstersaurus-rex) by Tom O'Donnell may be only a partial match. I haven't read it, but it matches the idea of the class pet turning into a dinosaur, although summaries seem to indicate that it's a side effect of the eponymous hamster eating illicit bodybuilding powder, not aliens. It's also more of a graphic novel.

[image: Front cover of Hamstersaurus Rex]

> When a mysterious growling hamster appears at the back of his class, Sam knows just what to call him: Hamstersaurus Rex. Sam tries to protect Hammie from an overzealous Hamster Monitor, and from the meanest bully in the history of Horace Hotwater Middle School. The bully isn’t afraid of some weird little class pet. But maybe he should be. Hamstersaurus Rex is no ordinary hamster.